# Handle caching at the data layer or React State layer

Tags: reactjs

Starting a new React app and really want try to avoid adding Redux, and just do everything in natively using hooks. One issue I am running into now is that between page navigations I am reloading data a lot.

I know I can just store this data in the Context api.

However I am wondering what if I just write the caching logic at the ServiceClient layer. All my React Views would request data on every mount/update, however the decision on whether to fetch from cache or network would happen at some ApiController level.

Typically I would store the normalized data on my Redux state, but that always just becomes kind of a pain to manage.

Does this make sense or is it an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a now in production app using this kind of logic. Whenever I was fetching large amounts of data (i.e. a list of some sort) this is basically how it would go:

1. View requests data to DataManager (a singleton) with onSuccess and OnFailure callbacks and the API call function.
2. The DataManager then checked if previous data matching the request was in memory and/or on disk via AsyncStorage. If so it called the onSuccess callback.
3. The DataManager made the API call to get the updated data and called onSuccess again which updated the view with the latest data.
4. If any error happened, the onFailure callback was invoked.

If you want something less complex you can use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org), which lets views keep their state between mounts/unmounts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion